# Converting a string to FileTime in java

Tags: java, swing, timestamp, java.nio.file

I have this problem.
PROBLEM:
I am making a program in which i am taking input from user via a `JFormatedTextField` i.e. in string format and then i want this value to be creation time of a file chosen by user.

So I need to uses setTimes() function which only accepts fileTime format.
So the PROBLEM is:::: **how do I convert the string into an eligible fileTime** so that it can be used by the function setTimes() which is predefined in .nio.attribute.

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html

Comment: And what is the input like, exactly?

Comment: doesn't the toString() work?

Comment: I think you need to restrict user to enter the date string in specific format. It is not assumption that, user will enter it in dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss format.!

Answer (score 3):

This would do the trick:

You have to change the date format (new SimpleDateFormat(...) like you give it in the text field and remove the main method indeed.

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String date = "01.01.2013 10:00:10";
long milis;
try {
    milis = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss").parse(date)
        .getTime();
    FileTime fileTime = FileTime.fromMillis(milis);
    System.out
        .println("Time: " + fileTime.toString());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: @Manuel.. I tried this out but this is not working and giving the error:::::::java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what the format of the input is (I suppose it is something like `"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss"`), you can convert this to a `Date` using `SimpleDateFormat`, from the `Date` you can get the milliseconds using `Date.getTime()` and finally use that value to build a `FileTime` with `java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime.fromMillis(long)`

Something like this should do it:

```
String text = textField.getText();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").parse(text);
FileTime time = FileTime.fromMillis(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I tried this out but this is not working and giving the error:::::::
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime
 at Interface.actionPerformed(Interface.java:166)

Comment: Okay this is working...Thanks a lot...
But i am facing one more problem...
The "filetime time" which i am using to save the creation time is updating the CTime creation time in JAVA but its not updating in os..i.e. when i am opening properties its showing old Time Stamp.. I am working on Win 8...Do you hav any idea

Comment: @user2500367 You can use the following snippet to update creation time: `BasicFileAttributeView fileAttributeView = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, BasicFileAttributeView.class);
  fileAttributeView.setTimes(null, null, FileTime.fromMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000));`