# Using FileTime To save Creation Time using setTImes()

Tags: java, swing, timestamp, java.nio.file

I have this problem.
PROBLEM:
i am making a program in which i am changing the TimeStamp of a file...

Problem::::
The code i have written is working fine::

```
String text = textField.getText();
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss").parse(text);
FileTime time = FileTime.fromMillis(date.getTime());
```

The problem is :::: "filetime time" which i am using to save the creation time is updating the CTime creation time in JAVA but its not updating in os..i.e. when i am opening properties its showing old Time Stamp.. I am working on Win 8

http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/FileTime.html

Comment: You show the code to create the `FileTime` instance here; what about the code to write the victim file's metadata? I don't see it here

Comment: See also this previous [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17187360/230513) on the same topic.